# foreground extraction in opencv using python

Tags: python, opencv, background-foreground

I am trying to do foreground extraction(Grab cut algorithm) in open CV using python. I am using the code from the [**link**](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/python2/grabcut.py) . The code runs but everytime I am moving the mouse it is drawing a rectangle.

**Problem:** I cannot draw the touching strokes even after pressing the 0,1,2,3 keys as mentioned. *Can someone please suggest how to come out of the rectangle mode and fix the rectangle after i release the mouse button.*

I am new to open CV,any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is structured very clearly. You might start by adding print statements in the `onmouse` method, in each of the

```
if event == ...
```

blocks, to figure out which events are correctly registered and which don't come through.